# Asp.NET Hiddenfield set $row as value

Tags: html, asp.net, object, row, hidden-field

I try to set my row in hiddenfield at get it back in another function.There is nothing wrong  at first $row value it is correct I use it in  A function

```
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSelectedFile" />

   // A function
   var $row = $(elem).closest("tr");
  $("[id*=hdnSelectedFile]").val($row);


     //another function
     // B function

      var $row = $("[id*=hdnSelectedFile]").val();
      if ($row != null && $row != "") {
        $($row).attr("data-showanswer", "0");
        $($row).attr("data-isdate", "0");
        $($row).attr("data-startdate", null);
        $($row).attr("data-finishdate", null);
        }
```

The error is  for my **$row**

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Comment: So which exact line throws the error?

Comment: Of course   var $row = $("[id*=hdnSelectedFile]").val();